# PHP unlink() problem with files named with multiple extensions

Tags: php, delete-file, unlink

I'm encountering an issue I've never come across before. I have some images uploaded as JPG or PNG with a duplicate of the image in WebP format, eg in this file naming convension:

`https://example.com/uploads/memory-day.png` > 
`https://example.com/uploads/memory-day.png.webp`

If I delete a file through PHP using the `unlink()` function like normal, it works fine for everything else **until** I delete the PNG duplicate image. When I do that, the WebP file is also deleted and I can't see how it's happening -- is it a weird issue in the `unlink()` function with a file having a double extension? I can't seem to replicate it unless it's there's a WebP file involved.

For clarity, here's the PHP code that deletes the files (and yeah, I know it needs to be a prepare statement, I haven't updated it yet):

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $countG = 0;
    $err = 0;
    foreach($_POST['delFile'] as $actionID) {
        $action_id = $conn->real_escape_string($actionID);

        $query = $conn->query("SELECT `filename`, `dir` FROM `fileuploads` WHERE `id` = '$action_id'");
        $delF = $query->fetch_assoc();
        $filenameDel = StripSlashes($delF['filename']);
        $filenameDir = StripSlashes($delF['dir']);
        if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $filenameDir . "/" . $filenameDel)){
            if(unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $filenameDir . "/" . $filenameDel)) {
                if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $filenameDir . "/auto_thumbs/" . $filenameDel)) {
                    unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $filenameDir . "/auto_thumbs/" . $filenameDel);
                }
                $delquery = $conn->query("DELETE FROM `fileuploads` WHERE `id` = '$action_id'");
                $countG++;
            } else {
                $err++;
            }
        } else {
            $err++;
            if(!file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $filenameDir . "/" . $filenameDel)) {
                //Remove from db if file is not there physically
                $delquery = $conn->query("DELETE FROM `fileuploads` WHERE `id` = '$action_id'");
            }
        }
    }
    if($countG > 0) {
        $green = 1;
        $message1 = "$countG File(s) Deleted!";
    }
    if($err > 0) {
        $red = 1;
        $message2 = "Error deleting $err files!";
        error_log(print_r(error_get_last(), TRUE));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection bla bla... Just kidding ;-)

Comment: If this is truly a bug in PHP you might consider a workaround. Do you generate the duplicate .png image yourself? In that case you could change the name of the duplicate image with a prefix or suffix.

Comment: Just a suggestion if I may. You could create another folder that would hold your `.webp` files. Having all of those files inside the same folder tend to complicate things.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner true, but the database table handles all the file management in a user interface, so the folder itself isn't much of an issue in this case.

Comment: @jrswgtr I am making the duplicates myself, but I need the file extensions as they are for an automatic fallback function I'm using on .htaccess for safari/iOS browsers. But I could try a prefix to see if that helps

Comment: @MrLewk I think you might be missing @Funk Forty Niners point. The directory itself COULD be the issue. Lets say your `.png` image's path is `/path/to/images/image.png` and your `.webp` path is  `/path/to/images/webp/image.png.webp`. If you unlink the png file, PHP might not unlink the webp image also because it's in a different directory.

Comment: @Rain If I `var_dump` I get the expected result of just the single ID of the file I selected: `array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "3951" }`

Comment: OK so, inexplicably, the issue has resolved itself and I have no idea how or why! I've tried everything to replicate it again and now everything works as expected and just the selected file is deleted! It's very bizarre. Thanks for all the help though trying to debug it!